# Performing precomputation when keras variables change

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, keras-layer

In keras/tensorflow, I have a custom layer whose definition looks schematically like this:

```python
class SlowLayer(keras.layer.Layer):
    def __init__(self):
        super(SlowLayer, self).__init__()
        self.weights = self.add_weight(shape=(100,100))

    def call(self, arg):
        permanent = super_slow_computation(self.weights)
        return arg*permanent + tf.reduce_sum(self.weights)
```

As written, this will perform super_slow_computation once for every batch. But that's not necessary: I ought to be able to run it only when the weights are updated, and then cache the result.

Does keras provide a facility for such things: functions of the weights alone, that don't depend on the inputs? What's a clean way to go about this?

Comment: The weights are updated once per batch, so you can use the same frequency and there should be no issues

Answer (score 0):

The weights are updated at the end of every batch, by default.
You can increase the batch size in order to increase the ratio of the number of examples per weights update.